# Iterate through logs and generate count of parameter

Tags: apache-pig

I have logs like below

```
stack-overflow is  awesome
apache-pig is really complex for starters
work from home in beginning was awesome
but now it sucks
```

and i have a parameter coming from a json file which has patterns i need to get the count of

```
regex='is|stackoverflow|awesome'
```

now i need to aggregate and find the count of each param in the file

so the task will be to get the below

```
is-2
stackoverflow-1
awesome-2
```

i need to load the param variable into tuple,
and then see if each variable exist in that like or not
following is my pseudo code

```
LOGS=LOAD LOG 
PARAMS =$PARAMS

FOREACH LOG IN LOGS:
    FOREACH PARAM IN PARAMS:
          IF PARAM IN LOG:
                  GENERATE PARAM,1

Then essentially group them and sum them up
```

the problem right now is , i am not able to load the param variable into a tuple of pig tuple

Is there any way this can be done, also is there any more optimal way of doing the above task??

Comment: does the regez have to be in a text string, you could make it tabular, read that in then don an in memory join. the group and count on the join

Comment: yes, i cant do anything about the input, the json file is coming from other team